# Fullcalendar v4 give the following error on load in lightning web component

Tags: salesforce, fullcalendar, salesforce-lightning

loaded the script core/main.js , daygrid/main.js, daygrid/main.css , core/main.css and got the following error on load

Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
throws at https://flow-momen[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEoak.png)tum-5169.lightning.force.com/resource/1557998143000/PA_rSp__FullCalendar:6:1128

.......

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

import fullcalendar from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/FullCalendar';

import fullcalendarcss from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/fullcalendarcss';

import daygrid from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/daygrid';

import daygridcss from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/daygridcss';

  import { loadScript, loadStyle }

                    from'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

 export default class Lwccalendar extends LightningElement 
 {

    renderedonce=false;

    renderedCallback()

    {

       if(this.renderedonce===true)

       {

         return;

       }

       this.renderonce=true;

       alert("here");

       Promise.all([

       loadScript(this, fullcalendar),


       loadScript(this, daygrid ),


       loadStyle(this, fullcalendarcss),        
       loadStyle(this, daygridcss)
       ])
        .then(() => {
            alert("here");
            this.rendercalendar();
        }).catch(error => {

              alert(error.message);
        });



}

rendercalendar()
{
    alert("here");
    let calendarEl=this.template.querySelector(`[data-id="calendar"]`);
    alert("got the dom");
    const calendarobj = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

      plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ]
      });

      calendarobj.render();
      alert("render complete");
    }

}
```

...

Comment: Were u able to get v4 working with lwc?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect two things might be at play here: <strike>1) I believe that FullCalendar requires both jQuery and moment.js.</strike> You'll want to load those as well *and* 2) I suspect that something weird is happening when loading dayGrid in the same Promise.all call as the base library. Try this instead:

```
Promise.all([
   loadScript(this, fullcalendar),
   loadStyle(this, fullcalendarcss)        
])
.then(() => {
    // load the FC plugin in the callback of the initial Promise.all
    Promise.all([
        loadScript(this, daygrid),
        loadStyle(this, daygridcss)
    ])
    .then(() => {
        this.rendercalendar();
    })
    .catch(error => {
        throw error;
    });
}).catch(error => {
    alert(error.message);
});
```

I had an issue with this as well, but I got it working after loading as above. I have no idea why this is the case as Promise.all is guaranteed to be strictly ordered. Very strange!

edit: It turns out that the jQuery and Moment libraries are only required pre-v4. Also, while the above code worked for me to load the FullCalendar plugin into a Lightning Web Component, I couldn't get **selectable: true** to work, even after importing the **interaction** plugin. I ended up reverting to version 3.7.0 of FullCalendar which worked great (though *did* require jQuery and Moment).